# DataProvider TestNG runs on one machine but not another

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am trying to execute same test step with two different credential users using DataProvider (TestNG - Selenium Java). I'm one user, and we'll call the other "Bob".

Bob was able to run the same exact code from his machine, but I cannot run the exact same code from my machine.

We have the same Selenium-Java (2.44.0) and TestNG (6.8.13) Versions.

Here is the code . Because the same code will be executed by two different `User Type`, we need to use `dataProvider` to run the code.

```
 @Test(enabled = true, dataProviderClass = Users.class, dataProvider = "alltestCredentials")
 public void profileTest(Credentials credentials) {   
    loginUser(credentials);
    ...            
    logout(); 
    }
}
```

The test log results are different:

Bob's machine:

> Thread # 1: Opening Firefox browser
> Thread # 1: Entering class: profileTest
> Thread # 1: Entering method: profileTest

My machine:

> Thread # 1: Opening Firefox browser
> Thread # 1: Entering class: profileTest
> Thread # 1: Preparing to exist class: profileTest
> Thread # 1: Exiting class: profileTest
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> Caused by: com.webtest.exception.TestException: username is mandatory

Why is the code running on Bob's machine, but not mine?

What else do I need to check to ensure that Bob and I really have the same systems?